# Excepción de java al exportar un pdf desde jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

Holaaa alguien, tengo una excepción de java neatbeans para exportar un pdf desde jasper, si alguien sabe la versión de itext para evitarla

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.itextpdf.text.Document.setRole(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName)'
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:580)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:519)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:157)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:505)
    at vista.Reportes.exportarPDF(Reportes.java:84)
    at vista.Reportes.jButton1ActionPerformed(Reportes.java:68)
    at vista.Reportes$1.actionPerformed(Reportes.java:43)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
```

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Revisá [esta respuesta](/a/329025) (especialmente el enlace citado).

Comment: Se [requiere](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-v6-requirements) iText 1.3.1 o posterior.

Comment: Tengo itext 5.12 y me sale ese error.